# Rejecting gravity effect SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

This's my first project using SpriteKit.

I'm using these nodes

```
let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
physicsBody.isAffectedByGravity = true
physicsBody.mass = 1
geometryNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
let force = SCNVector3(0, 9.8, 0)
let position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
geometryNode.physicsBody?.applyForce(force, at: position, asImpulse: false)
scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)
```

My goal is to see the object stuck in the centre of my scene.

As read within SceneKit's documentation, SceneKit uses SI so Mass 1 means 1 kg.

Gravity force applied to the mass centre of this object is -9.8N ( 1kg * 9.8 m/s^2 ) on the Y-axis.
Applying 9.8N to the mass centre should bring the resultant force equal to 0 so no one force is applied and the object should be stuck in the centre but in my project, it falls down.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you apply the force when you create the node.

From the developer docs on applyForce:

> Discussion This method accelerates the body without imparting any 
>   angular acceleration to it. The acceleration is applied  for a single
>   simulation step (one frame).

I think you need to move your applyForce call to your update method in the scene. so that the force is constantly applied.

Comment: This is definitely the solution. It helped me to understand why I should move that line of code within ` renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`